# Upload image using mono for android not working

Tags: php, mono, xamarin.android

I am trying to upload an image  using the following mono code on android 2.2 
but nothing gets uploaded.

On the server i have a php file that gets and saves the image file, code works fine with C# 4.0 when i replace below line

```
string path = "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/" + "abc.jpg";
```

With

```
string path = @"C:/images/" + "abc.jpg";
```

Please advise

```
  void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  { 

  ManualResetEvent evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);
  WebClient wc = new WebClient();

  string path = "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/" + "abc.jpg";

  wc.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(CB);
  wc.UploadFileAsync(new Uri("http://mywebsite.com/upload.php"), "POST", path, evt);

  evt.WaitOne();

  }

  static void CB(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
  {

        if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File uploaded");

        }
        else
        {
            //Toast.MakeText(this, e.Error.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error.ToString());
        }
        ((ManualResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
  }
```

Comment: Deleted FTP terms from title and the question, as you are sending the image using HTTP POST, not FTP.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Are you sure that's the correct path to the file? (Hard-coding the path like that is generally a bad idea) Can you access that URL in the browser? What does the debug log say?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up uploading images directly to the FTP following instructions from here

http://memorypointer.com/uploading-image-to-ftp-mono-for-android/

thought it might help others